# Fill region and add a vertical or horizontal strip inside

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, labels

[image]Question:1 How can i fill region between points A(2,0) and B(2,0) with different colors?

Question:1 How can i add a small size (width approximately 0.25 cm) vertical strip with upper-lower labeling in this region?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1cm,y=1cm]
        \begin{axis}[
        x=1cm,y=1cm,
        axis lines=middle,
        axis line style={stealth-stealth},
        %ymajorgrids=true,
        %xmajorgrids=true,
        xmin=-4,
        xmax=4,
        ymin=-4.,
        ymax=4.0,
        xtick=\empty,
        ytick=\empty,]
        \draw [line width=0.8pt,color=black] (0,0) circle (2cm);
        \draw [line width=0.8pt,color=black,<->,domain=-2.0:4] plot(\x,{(--2-1*\x)/1});
        \draw[color=black] (-1.8,2.2) node {$x^2+y^2=4$};
        \draw [fill=black] (0,0) circle (2.5pt);
        \draw[color=black] (-0.7,-0.3444875776397527) node {$O(0 , 0)$};
        \draw [fill=black] (2,0) circle (2.5pt);
        \draw[color=black] (2.828881987577652,0.30) node {$A(2 , 0)$};
        \draw [fill=black] (0,2) circle (2.5pt);
        \draw[color=black] (0.8,2.4) node {$B(0 ,2)$};
        \draw [fill=black] (-2,0) circle (2.5pt);
        \draw[color=black] (-3,0.30) node {$C(-2 , 0)$};
        \draw [fill=black] (0,-2) circle (2.5pt);
        \draw[color=black] (-0.9,-2.5) node {$D(0 , -2)$};
        \draw[color=black] (2.8,-1.6) node[rotate=-42] {$x+y=2$};
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you give more details on your second question? Do you want a single strip (a line) or do you want to hatch a region (with a stripped pattern)? What do you mean by "upper-lower" labeling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question is not clear, so I limited myself to @JuCa understanding of it that you like to have colored above region between line L and circle C.

An alternative/supplement to nice [JuCa answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/575353/fill-region-and-add-a-vertical-or-horizontal-strip-inside/575370#575370) (+1). From his/OP code are removed not needed options, in `fill between` is used `split` option for segmentation of intersections, other small changes are marked by `% <---` in code:

```
\documentclass[margin=3.14159]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}       % <---
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}    % <---
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
         > = Straight Barb,     % <---
dot/.style = {circle, fill=black, inner sep=0pt, minimum width=6pt,
              node contents={}} % <---
                     ]
\begin{axis}[
    x=1cm, y=1cm,
    axis lines=middle,
    axis line style={<->},
    xmin=-4,    xmax=4,
    ymin=-4,    ymax=4,
    xtick=\empty,
    ytick=\empty
            ]
% Circle: C
\draw[very thick, name path=C] (0,0) circle[radius=2cm]; % <---
\node[pin=above left:{$x^2+y^2=4$}] at (135:2) {};       % <---
% Line: L
\draw[very thick, <->, name path=L] 
    (-2,4) -- (0, 2) node[dot, label=above right:{$B(0,2)$}]  % <--
           -- (2, 0) node[dot, label=above right:{$A(2,0)$}]  % <--
           -- node[sloped,above] {$x+y=2$} (4,-2);
% fill between C and L    
\addplot [red] fill between[of = L and C, split,         % <---
               every even segment/.style={fill=none}     %
                           ];
% remaining dots
\path   (-2,0) node[dot, label=above left:{$O( 0, 0)$}]  % <---
        (0,-2) node[dot, label=below left:{$C(-2, 0)$}]  % <---
        (0, 0) node[dot, label=below left:{$D( 0,-2)$}]; % <---
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit (2):**
After editing of question, it seems (I still guessing) that strip can be of any color and should not protrude out of colored region. This requirement  require a somewhat more complex code.

**Edit (3):**
Code for strip is simplified.

**Edit (4):**
Strip design is changes according to the last OP commentis simplified.

```
\documentclass[margin=3.14159]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
         > = Straight Barb,
dot/.style = {circle, fill=black, inner sep=0pt, minimum width=6pt,
              node contents={}},
                     ]
\begin{axis}[
    x=1cm,y=1cm,
    axis lines=middle,
    axis line style={<->},
    xmin=-4,    xmax=4,
    ymin=-4,    ymax=4,
    xtick=\empty,
    ytick=\empty
            ]
% Circle
\draw[very thick, name path=C] (0,0) circle[radius=2cm];
\node[pin=above left:{$x^2+y^2=4$}] at (135:2) {};
% Line: L
\draw[very thick, <->, name path=L]
    (-2,4) -- (0, 2) node[dot, label=above right:{$B(0,2)$}]
           -- (2, 0) node[dot, label=above right:{$A(2,0)$}]
           -- node[sloped,above] {$x+y=2$} (4,-2);
% fill circle segments
\addplot [red] fill between[of = L and C, split,
                            every even segment/.style={fill=none}
         ];
% strip: calculation of coordinates for strip
\path[name path=S]  (0.9,2) -- (0.9,0) 
                    (1.1,2) -- (1.1,0);
\path[name intersections={of=S and C, by={s11,s12}}];
\path[name intersections={of=S and L, by={s21,s22}}];
% strip: draw left and right border, fill area
\draw[very thick, fill=teal!50] 
      (s11) -- (s21) -- node[below] {$Q$} (s22) -- (s12);
\path (s11) -- node[above] {$P$} (s12);
% remaining dots
\path   (-2,0) node[dot, label=above left:{$O( 0, 0)$}]
        (0,-2) node[dot, label=below left:{$C(-2, 0)$}]
        (0, 0) node[dot, label=below left:{$D( 0,-2)$}];
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In my second question I wish to draw a thin strip inside the filled region and exactly in the cente. In other words two vertical lines inside the filled region.

Comment: Please help me this is my request..I can upload my desire outcome figure by editing my question, if require..

Comment: Sketch means what? I need to draw two vertical lines inside filled region and label upper end of this strip as P and lower end Q

Comment: strip must be inside region. Should not go outside the region

Comment: No problem but I hope that you will definitely finish for me. Thanks a lot

Comment: Exactly which i wanted... Thanks but due to strip some part of line and circle don't looks clear..

Comment: @Snehal, meanwhile I succeed to simplified code for strip. Code with added comments  should be self explained, however if it is needed I can add some more explanation.

Comment: Sir Can you make some modification in your code so that hide parts visible

Comment: @Snehal, sorry, I don't understand which changes you like to have. What you mean with *that hide parts visible*?

Comment: See the final output just below P some part of circle is not visible as well as just above Q some part of line is not visible due to the filling of that strip. I hope you are getting what i am trying to say...

Comment: @Snehal, ok. See edited anser, this time is the last time :-)

Comment: Exactly Sir,,,, I knew that you spent lots of time for me... Once again thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question: you can fill areas between paths. To define a path within the axis environment:
`\path[name path = name_of_your_path] (x1,y1) -- (x2,y2);`.

Then, you can fill the area between two paths:
`\addplot [your_color] fill between[of = name_of_your_path_1 and name_of_your_path_2, soft clip = {domain=x1:x2}];`

Here, the two paths are defining the boundaries of the area on the y axis and the soft clip is defining the boundaries on the x axis.

I do not completely understand what you want to do with your second question.

Additionally, it is easier to define a a type of `node` named `point` and to give it a style so you can directly place a node and label it. The main advantage is to place the node on paths.

The resulting code produces:
[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1cm,y=1cm,
        point/.style={circle, fill=black, inner sep=0pt, minimum width=5.5pt}]
        \begin{axis}[
        x=1cm,y=1cm,
        axis lines=middle,
        axis line style={stealth-stealth},
        %ymajorgrids=true,
        %xmajorgrids=true,
        xmin=-4,
        xmax=4,
        ymin=-4.,
        ymax=4.0,
        xtick=\empty,
        ytick=\empty,]
        \draw [line width=0.8pt,color=black] (0,0) circle (2cm);
        \path [draw,line width=0.8pt,color=black,<->,name path=myLine] (-2,4) -- (0,2) node[point, label=above right:{$B(0 ,2)$}] {} -- (2,0) node[point, label=above right:{$A(2 , 0)$}] {} --(4, -2);
        \path[name path= myArc] (2,0) arc(0:90:2);
        \addplot [red] fill between[of = myLine and myArc, soft clip = {domain=0:2}];
        \draw[color=black] (-1.8,2.2) node {$x^2+y^2=4$};
        \node[point, label=below left:{$O(0 , 0)$}] at (0,0) {};
        \node[point, label=above left:{$C(-2 , 0)$}] at (-2,0) {};
        \node[point, label=below left:{$D(0 , -2)$}] at (0,-2) {};
        \draw[color=black] (2.8,-1.6) node[rotate=-42] {$x+y=2$};
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying my first question